# No priority (or zero) specified for pin

Tags: apt

This error appears always when I try to install or uninstall any package:

```
sudo apt-get remove lynx

Reading package lists... Done

E: No priority (or zero) specified for pin
```

Comment: Run `apt-cache policy` and any pins should be listed after `Pinned packages:`.  Then check in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/` if there is any files containing something about pin.

Comment: apt-cache policy returns: **No priority (or zero) specified for pin**. There's only one file in preferences.d - **ubuntu-esm-infra-trusty**. Contains next text: 
`# Written by ubuntu-advantage-tools
Package: *
Pin: release o=UbuntuESM, n=trusty
Pin-Priority: never
~`

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu 14.04 with ESM enabled?  If so, I believe you contact their support for help on this:  https://ubuntu.com/esm  I don't know what priority the ESM is supposed to be set to.  I've read in places that pinning goes with the higher the number the more priority it gets.

Comment: It actually happened after update from 14 to 16, i have no clue about ESM, everything works except apt

Comment: Then I am guessing that the file can be removed or moved to another folder.  I would try again after that.  That file is for Extended Support from Canonical after the version went EOL.  Since 16.04 is not EOL you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the comments above, there is a file of `ubuntu-esm-infra-trusty` in the `/etc/apt/preferences.d/` folder that contains a pin with no value on its priority.  This file is for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty ESM, but since you are running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS this file is not needed.  Remove the file and you should be fine.